# Подогнать ширину под размер текста

Tags: css

Использую `--width: 140px;` фиксированную ширину. Подогнала под большой текст, но если текст маленький, смотрится не очень

Как можно задать ширину `в зависимости от длины текста` ?  Возможно ли расчитать длину текста ?

```css
.toggle {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  --width: 140px;
  --height: calc(var(--width) / 4);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border-radius: var(--height);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--height);
  background-color: #dee0e3;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .slider::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--height));
  height: calc(var(--height));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#btn1 input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#btn2 input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: pink;
}

.toggle input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - var(--height)));
}

.toggle .labels {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::after {
  content: attr(data-off);
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::before {
  content: attr(data-on);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle" id="btn1">
    <input type="checkbox" @oninput="orderBy1Async" checked="@isChecked1">
    <span class="slider"></span>
    <span class="labels" 
    data-on="длинный текст..." data-off="длинный текст...">
    </span>
</label>

<label class="toggle" id="btn2">
    <input type="checkbox" @oninput="orderBy2Async" checked="@isChecked2">
    <span class="slider"></span>
    <span class="labels" 
    data-on=":-)" data-off=":-)">
    </span>
</label>
```

если невозомжно расчитать размер текста, то как бы вы поступили, чтоб уменьшить размер фиксированно, для второй кнопки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст будет задаваться в инлайновый элемент (к премеру `<span>`) его длинна, по умолчанию будет зависить от размера текста. Если же ваш элемент `.toggle` `<div>` `<p>` - блочный элемент (по умолчанию), то текст растягиваеться на всю длинну родителя. Фиксировать ширину блока, это не очень хорошая идея если у вас адаптивная страница.
Ещё можете использовать инлайновый элемент и значение `min-width:` если вам кретично.

Comment: спасибо за отзыв, в этой кнопке текст в спане, но когда я поставила ширину авто, то все съежилось, может не тот класс трогаю, просто все базируется на классе тогл, а спан-текст-класс---labels, но если я его трону все сломаю наверно

Comment: поиграйтесь с min-width\max-width